# Cannot access file error Latest Visual studio - Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am getting this error while running on emulator or device:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\TFS\RRR\ABC\MobileApps\SampleApp\SampleApp\SampleApp.Droid\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\SampleApp.Droid.dll' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.File.OpenFile(String path, FileAccess access, SafeFileHandle& handle)
   at System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(String path, DateTime lastWriteTimeUtc)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfChanged(String source, String destination)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.CopyAssemblyAndSymbols(String source, String destination)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssembliesNoShrink.RunTask()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()   SampleApp.Droid
```

I tried to clean the projects' binaries and rerun but it doesn't help. Reinstall doesn't help either. I keep getting the same error. Visual studio, ADB is updated.

Comment: You could create a new blank project to confirm if it the issue of the IDE or just in the specific project . If the issue exists in new project , report the issue **Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a problem** .

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT , i did try creating fresh project and still getting the error. I am going to report this.

Comment: Thanks for your replay and we will focus on it .